# Replace an item, keep spacing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button that is being replaced with a loading cog (using jquery).

When it is replaced the page gets shorter, due to the cog being smaller.

How can I replace the button and keep the page spacing?

Apply the same css spacing to the cog? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Puts hide the button element, using `visibility: hidden;` and position the 'cog' appropriately, perhaps with `position: absolute;` to avoid causing a page reflow.

Should you show some representative code, I can (try to) provide a more complete answer.